# How to select none if condition is not?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to do a simple query to select from a database and only select rows which fit to the statement of being older than 12 months.

The table is like (mydate actually is a datetime field):

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | account | mydate      |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 1  | 1       | last week   | <-- this should disqualify account 1
| 2  | 1       | 2 years ago |
| 3  | 1       | 3 years ago |
| 4  | 2       | 2 years ago |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

And this is my query by now:

```
SELECT id, account, MAX(mydate)
FROM awesomeTable
WHERE
  mydate < SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY account
```

Seems nice. But the results are like following:

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | account | mydate      |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 2  | 1       | 2 years ago | <-- SQL doesnt understand me :(
| 4  | 2       | 2 years ago |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

But I don't want to let account 2 show up at all. I really just want to see accounts where mydate is older than 2 years.

With that query now it doesnt show ID 1 as this doesnt fit the condition in the WHERE clause. But it will show me the newest possible mydate of the other rows.

I want to get a list of all accounts which mydates are ALL older than 1 year. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There `WHERE` condition is done to select the rows first, then `MAX()` is applied to those results. Use `HAVING` to operate on the results after aggregating.

```
SELECT id, account, MAX(mydate) AS maxdate
FROM awesometable
GROUP BY account
HAVING maxdate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
```

Note that this will not necessarily show the `id` of the line with the maximum date. For that, you need a join:

```
SELECT a.id, a.account, a.mydate
FROM awesometable AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT account, MAX(mydate) AS maxdate
    FROM awesometable
    GROUP BY account
    HAVING maxdate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)) AS b
ON a.account = b.account AND a.mydate = b.maxdate
```

Comment: I can't get that script to work, though it looks correct. `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY account limit 0,100000' at line 4 SQL.sql"` - The mySQL Server is version 5.5.

Comment: Sorry about that, GROUP BY comes before HAVING.

Comment: And - magic - it works! Haven't seen that, too. Thanks for your answer, helped me a lot!